# Cut a variable differently based on another grouping variable

Tags: r, dplyr, aggregate, tapply, split-apply-combine

Example: I have a dataset of heights by gender.
I'd like to split the heights into low and high where the cut points are defined as the mean - 2sd within each gender.

example dataset:

```
set.seed(8)
df = data.frame(sex = c(rep("M",100), rep("F",100)), 
                ht = c(rnorm(100, mean=1.7, sd=.17), rnorm(100, mean=1.6, sd=.16)))
```

I'd like to do something in a single line of vectorized code because I'm fairly sure that is possible, however, I do not know how to write it.  I imagine that there may be a way to use `cut()`, `apply()`, and/or `dplyr` to achieve this.

Comment: What was it about my question that caused people to down vote?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just discovered the following solution using base r:

```
df$ht_grp <- ave(x = df$ht, df$sex, 
                 FUN = function(x) 
                       cut(x, breaks = c(0, (mean(x, na.rm=T) - 2*sd(x, na.rm=T)), Inf)))
```

This works because I know that 0 and Inf are reasonable bounds, but I could also use `min(x)`, and `max(x)` as my upper and lower bounds.  This results in a factor variable that is split into low, high, and NA.

---

My prior solution:
I came up with the following two-step process which is not so bad:

```
df = merge(df, 
           setNames( aggregate(ht ~ sex, df, FUN = function(x) mean(x)-2*sd(x)), 
                     c("sex", "ht_cutoff")), 
           by = "sex")

df$ht_is_low = ifelse(df$ht <= df$ht_cutoff, 1, 0)
```

Comment: `df %>% group_by(sex) %>% mutate(ht_is_low = as.integer(ht < mean(ht) - 2*sd(ht)))`

Answer (score 1):

How about this using `cut` from base R:

```
sapply(c("F", "M"), function(s){
    dfF <- df[df$sex==s,] # filter out per gender
    cut(dfF$ht, breaks = c(0, mean(dfF$ht)-2*sd(dfF$ht), Inf), labels = c("low", "high"))
})
# dfF$ht heights per gender
# mean(dfF$ht)-2*sd(dfF$ht) cut point
```

Answer (score 0):

In the code below, I created 2 new variables. Both were created by grouping the `sex` variable and filtering the different ranges of `ht`.

```
 library(dplyr)
 df_low <- df %>% group_by(sex) %>% filter(ht<(mean(ht)-2*sd(ht)))
 df_high<- df %>% group_by(sex) %>% filter(ht>(mean(ht)+2*sd(ht)))
```